# Why does the molar conductivity plot behave this way?

Tags: electrochemistry, concentration, conductivity

On the left image.. we see that specific conductivity is increasing at a decreasing rate, eventually plateauing as it reaches a maximum. I am unable to reconcile this with the molar conductivity graph to the right... shouldn't the decreasing molar conductivity be decreasing at an increasing rate... why does it plateau and such? Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: have you checked the units in the right graph?

Comment: One effect is crowding -- not enough room for ions to be mobile. See https://byjus.com/chemistry/variations-molar-conductivity/ . Also, as @Karl states, one abscissa inlcudes concentration...

Comment: I dont follow why molar conductivity is concave up .. shouldnt it be concave down?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It should. Check again. ;)

Comment: Yes it should... that was a *hint* to the bewildered.

Comment: A math note: AFAIK, a concave function is the one with y'' < 0, bending down. A convex one is the one with y'' > 0, bending up.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't know if the curve is correct, but the ordinate has a unit that does not make sense. It must be $\rm{S cm^2 mol^{-1}}$.

Comment: @Karl uhh all the graphs i find online follow this general shape.. i thought it should be concave down though?

Comment: @Poutnik based on that definition.. the curve above is convex.. but i thought it should be concave? like since the curve on the left increases at a decreasing rate.. it should follow the curve on the right is bending down?

Comment: Well, the concentration range is at quite big numbers. But following the Kohlrauch law for molar conductivities at very low concentrations, it is convex even there : $\Lambda = \Lambda_0 - const \cdot \sqrt {c}$.